# How to make nginx use a different mongrel to the one which is handling the current request?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, mongrel, mongrel-cluster

On our site we have a 12 mongrel cluster running, and in my local dev version i have a 5 mongrel cluster.  nginx (`version: nginx/1.22.0`) sits in front.

One of our processes makes a pdf by shelling out to wkhtmltopdf, a command line tool, which in turn calls the website to get a page which it then turns into a pdf.

That is working, except that sometimes the request for the page goes to the same mongrel (always mongrel 1) that shelled out, and then I have a deadlock - the first request is waiting for the second one to be finished, but the second one is in a queue after the first one.

```
Mongrel Top (delay: 0.25)                                                                                                                                                                 Fri Sep 22 16:47:59 2023

65347 sh -c start -p 3000 & mongrel_rails start -p 3001 & mongrel_rails start -p 3002 & mongrel_rails start -p 3003 & mongrel_rails start -p 3004
65348 [3000/2/11]: handling 127.0.0.1: POST /admin/school_quotes/CMS1Y-187790-107226, 127.0.0.1: GET /
65349 [3001/0/0]: idle
65350 [3002/0/0]: idle
65351 [3003/0/0]: idle
65352 [3004/0/0]: idle

6 process(es)
```

In my nginx config, i've been trying to get it to use a different mongrel than the one which is currently busy, but with no success - it always just seems to pick one at random and so has a 20% chance of picking the same one and locking up.  (although it feels more like 50%)

The relevant nginx config block currently looks like this:

```
upstream elrs {
  # least_conn;
  # random two;
  # round_robin;
  zone backends 128k;
  server 127.0.0.1:3000 max_conns=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=2;
  server 127.0.0.1:3001 max_conns=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=2;
  server 127.0.0.1:3002 max_conns=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=2;
  server 127.0.0.1:3003 max_conns=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=2;
  server 127.0.0.1:3004 max_conns=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=2;
}
```

I set `max_conns` to 1 on all of them thinking that might fix it but it hasn't.
I also tried the `least_conn` option but the second or third time I tried they both ended up on mongrel 1 again.

I tried `round_robin` after reading about it but I get an error from that - `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "round_robin"`

Any advice appreciated, thanks.